# Proving $|P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)|\leq \frac{1}4$

Tags: probability, inequality

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two events of a probability space. Prove that  $\displaystyle|P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)|\leq \frac{1}4$

I think it's a very challenging problem, and I've made no progress so far ...

Can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: One not difficult is: $|P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)|\leq \frac{1}4\vert P(A| B)-P(A|B^{C})\vert$

Comment: @Krokop Very nice. Maybe less cryptic: show the algebraic identity $$P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)=P(B)P(B^c)(P(A\mid B)-P(A\mid B^c)).$$

Comment: Hint: what if $A$ and $B$ are exclusive?

Comment: @Ertxiem In this case we have to show that $P(A)P(B) < \frac 1 4$. Since $A \cap B = \null$, we have $B \subset \bar{A}$ thus we have the inequality (because $P(A) P(\bar{A}) < \frac 1 4$ is clear).

Comment: Hint: In other case : $P (A \cap B) < min(P(A),P(B))$

Comment: And if $A$ and $B$ are complementary?

Comment: Note that if $A$ and $B$ are complementary, your equation becomes $| x (1-x) | \leq \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @Ertxiem What if $A$ and $B$ are not exclusive?

Comment: Then $P(A \cap B) \geq 0$. And remember that $P(B) \leq 1- P(A)$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since $P(A)\ge P(A\cap B)$ and $P(B)\ge P(A\cap B)$ you have that $$P(A)P(B)\ge P(A\cap B)^2$$ which gives $$P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\le P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap B)^2=P(A\cap B)(1-P(A\cap B))$$ Now for $p:=P(A\cap B)$, the right hand side is equal to $$f(p)=p(1-p)$$ for $p\in [0,1]$. This function is a quadratic function that attains it's maximum in the midpoint between it's roots ($p=0$ and $p=1$), that is at $p=1/2$.

---

Now the other side follows from the first side, if you use that $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B')=P(A)$ or equivalently $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B')$$ which gives you that $$P(A)P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)-P(A)+P(A\cap B')=P(A\cap B')-P(A)P(B')$$ where the right hand side is $\le \dfrac{1}{4}$ due to first inequality we proved above (since the above inequality holds for every $A,B$, it holds also for $B'$ in place of $B$). This gives you also the other side.

Comment: Only one side of the inequality.

Comment: Nice proof, thanks. Did you toil to make it? I don't find the second part very natural.

Comment: @G.T.R You are welcome. I came up with the second part by chance. Yes, it took me some time making calculations and trying different things until I saw it.

Comment: @Jimmy R., Respected Mr. Jimmy R., explain, please, why do You think that $P(A)\ge P(A\cap B)$ and $P(B)\ge P(A\cap B)$?

Answer (score 9):

Note that

$\begin{align}
|P(A\cap B) - P(A)P(B)| &= |E[1_A1_B] - E[1_A]E[1_B]|\\
&= |Cov(1_A,1_B)|\\
&= |E[\{1_A-P(A)\}\{1_B-P(B)\}]| \\
&\leq \sqrt{V(1_A)}\sqrt{V(1_B)}
\end{align}$

where the last inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwarz for the following inner product on $L^2(P)$
$$\langle X,Y\rangle = E[XY].$$

Next, $V(1_A) = E[1_A^2] - E[1_A]^2 = E[1_A] - E[1_A]^2 = E[1_A](1-E[1_A])\leq \frac 14$, hence the claim.

Comment: Your proof is based on a good idea, I've formatted it with Latex.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most succinct proof, shamelessly adapted from another answer:

If $P(B)=0$ or $P(B)=1$ the inequality is trivial, so we may assume $P(B)\in (0,1)$. Then note that $$\begin{align}|P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)|
&= \left|P(B)P(B^c)\left[ \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)P(B^c)} - \frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} \right]\right|\\ 
&= \left|P(B)P(B^c)\left[\frac{P(A\cap B)(1-P(B))}{P(B)P(B^c)}-\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} \right]\right|\\
&=P(B)P(B^c)|P(A\mid B)-P(A\mid B^c)|\\
&=P(B)(1-P(B))\underbrace{|P(A\mid B)-P(A\mid B^c)|}_{\leq 1}\\
&\leq \frac 14
\end{align}$$

because $x(1-x)\leq \frac 14$ when $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get how $|P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)|
=P(B)P(B^c)|P(A\mid B)-P(A\mid B^c)|$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash this is straightforward algebra $$\begin{aligned}P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B) &= P(B)P(B^c)\left[ \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)P(B^c)} - \frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} \right]\\ &= P(B)P(B^c)\left[\frac{P(A\cap B)(1-P(B))}{P(B)P(B^c)}-\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} \right]\end{aligned}$$

Comment: You have a weird definition of _straightforward_. @GabrielRomon

Comment: @Gabriel Romon : Thank you for clarifying, that was nice idea. I learn something more.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I suggest to include the steps in your comment into the answer.

Comment: Why did you answer the question if you knew it was a duplicate?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Because it already had 3 answers.

Answer (score 3):

first, look at this, $$0 \leq x \leq1 \to x(1-x)\leq \frac 14$$
 now  if $$* \space 0\leq y\leq x\leq1 \to y(1-x)\leq x(1-x)\leq \frac 14$$
and 
  if $$** \space 0\leq x\leq y\leq1 \to x(1-y)\leq y(1-y)\leq \frac 14$$
we know $$P(A \cap B)\leq \min \{P(A ),P(B) \}\leq \max \{P(A ),P(B) \}$$
first suppose $P(A)=x,P( B)=y,y\leq x$
with respect to *
you will have 
$$|P(A\cap B)−P(A)P(B)|\leq |\max \{P(A ),P(B) \}−P(A)P(B)|=|x-xy|=|x(1-y)|≤\frac{1}{4}$$
as a second step,suppose $P(A)=x,P( B)=y,y\geq x$

you will have
(with respect to **)
$$|P(A\cap B)−P(A)P(B)|\leq |\max \{P(A ),P(B) \}−P(A)P(B)|=|y-xy|=|y(1-x)|≤\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let's call $\;P(A)=x\;$, $\;P(B)=y\;$, and suppose $x\le y$.
  We have

$$
\max\{0,x+y-1\}\le P(A\cap B)\le \min\{x,y\}=x
$$
Then, if $\;P(A\cap B)\ge xy\;$, we have
$$
|P(A\cap B)-xy|=P(A\cap B)-xy\le x-xy\le x-x^2\le \frac{1}{4}
$$

On the other hand, if $\;P(A\cap B)\le xy\;$, and $\;x+y\le 1\;$, 
$$
|P(A\cap B)-xy|=xy-P(A\cap B)\le xy\le x(1-x)\le \frac{1}{4}
$$

The last case is $\;P(A\cap B)\le xy\;$,  and $\;x+y\ge 1\;$, 
$$
|P(A\cap B)-xy|=xy-P(A\cap B)\le xy-x-y+1=(1-x)(1-y)\le x(1-x)\le \frac{1}{4}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $P(A), P(B), P(A \cap B) \geq 0$.

We have 2 cases:

- Case 1: $P(A \cap B) \leq P(A)P(B)$. In this case, let $P(A) = x \in [0; 1]$. Thus $P(B) \leq 1-x + P(A \cap B)$. Hence
  $$
  | P(A \cap B) - P(A)P(B) | \leq | P(A \cap B)(x-1) + x(1-x) | \leq x(1-x)
  $$
- Case 2: $P(A \cap B) \geq P(A)P(B)$. In this case, let $P(A \cap B) = y \in [0; 1]$, $P(A) = y + u$ and $P(B) = y + v$ for some small but non-negative values of $u$ and $v$. Hence
  $$
  | P(A \cap B) - P(A)P(B) | = | y - y^2 - yu - yv - uv | \leq y(1-y)
  $$

Comment: I ask to the downvoter to please tell me how can I improve my post.

Answer (score 2):

We have $2$ cases. Either $\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) \le \mathbb P(A \cap B)$ or $\mathbb P(A \cap B) \le \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)$.

Doing the **first one**:

We have then LHS: $\mathbb P(A \cap B) - \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) $.

Note that both $\mathbb P(A \cap B) \le \mathbb P(A)$ and $\mathbb P(A \cap B) \le \mathbb P(B)$ holds, so we can bound the LHS by (both):

$\mathbb P(A)(1-\mathbb P(B))$ and $\mathbb P(B)(1-\mathbb P(A))$. By multiplying those we get $\mathbb P(A)(1-\mathbb P(A)) \cdot \mathbb P(B)(1-\mathbb P(B))$

Using $x(1-x) \le \frac{1}{4}$ if $x \in [0,1]$ we get that the product is bounded by $\frac{1}{16}$ so at least one of $\mathbb P(A)(1-\mathbb P(B))$, $\mathbb P(B)(1-\mathbb P(A))$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{4}$.

Now for the **second one**:

Our LHS : $\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(A \cap B)$.

Note that $\mathbb P(A \cap B) \ge \max\{ \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) - 1, 0\}$

Again we can have $2$ cases:

1) if $0 \ge \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) - 1$, then we can bound LHS by $\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)$, but since $\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) \le 1$ we get that $\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) \le \min\{ \mathbb P(A)(1-\mathbb P(B)) , \mathbb P(B)(1-\mathbb P(A)) \}$, which we showed earlier is less than $\frac{1}{4}$

2) if $0 \le \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) - 1$, we can bound LHS by $\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(A) -\mathbb P(B) + 1$ and then it is enough to show:

$\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(A) - \mathbb P(B) \le -\frac{3}{4}$ which is equal to

$\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) \ge \frac{3}{4} $

But we have (in this case) $\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) \ge 1$. So let $\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) = 1 + t$ for some $t \in [0,1]$. Obviously, $\mathbb P(A) \in [0,1]$, too.

We get $1 + t - (1+t-\mathbb P(A))\mathbb P(A) \ge \frac{3}{4}$

All we have to do is find maximum of $(1+t - \mathbb P(A))\mathbb P(A))$ with fixed $t \in [0,1]$. Looking at derivative, with respect to $\mathbb P(A)$ we get it's equal to $(1 + t -\mathbb P(A)) - \mathbb P(A) = 1+t - 2\mathbb P(A)$ and it equals $0$ iff $\mathbb P(A) = \frac{1+t}{2}$ which is a maximum ( due to our parabola having $-$ near square power)

Plugging it, we get $1 + t - (\frac{1+t}{2})(\frac{1+t}{2}) $, and writing $\frac{1+t}{2} = s$, we get $2s-s^2 - \frac{3}{4} \ge 0$, where $s \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$

Again, looking for minimum, we get it's either at $\frac{1}{2}$ or $1$

Plugging those values, we get both are $\ge 0$, so our first inequality is true.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof (quite similar to others already written here) for the mega-powerful Edith Kosmanek's inequality :

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ a probability space.

Notice that $\{A, \overline{A}\}$ is a complete system of events of $\mathcal{F}$. Hence using the formulum of total probabilities we get :

$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)= \mathbb{P}(\overline{A})\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) - \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(\overline{A}\cap B)$.

Also remark that for any $A$ and $B$ which are exclusive events of $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\le \dfrac{1}{4}$. Indeed using the increasing property of the probability measure and the fact that $B \subseteq \overline{A}$ we get that : $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\le \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(\overline{A})= \mathbb{P}(A)-(\mathbb{P}(A))^2 \le \dfrac{1}{4}$ (quick study of the function $x \mapsto x(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$).

Consequently we have that $\overline{A}$ and $A\cap B$ are exclusive events of $\mathcal{F}$ and it is the same thing for $A$ and $\overline{A}\cap B$.

Hence $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\le \dfrac{1}{4}-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(\overline{A}\cap B) \le \dfrac{1}{4}$. Indeed, $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(\overline{A}\cap B)\in [0,\frac{1}{4}]$.

And $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)- \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \le \dfrac{1}{4}- \mathbb{P}(\overline{A})\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \le \dfrac{1}{4}$. Indeed, $\mathbb{P}(\overline{A})\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \in [0, \frac{1}{4}]$.

Then we finally get : $\vert \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) \vert \le \dfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: This inequality is due to Edith Kosmanek ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Absolutely ! She's a French probabilist quite well-known ! But in the world of probabilities you have bunch of very well-known and famous inequalities from great mathematicians, it is really scary !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice simple proof that is just algebra and a tad of high school calculus.

First, to do careful book-keeping, we write $P(A=a,B=b)$ instead $P(A\cap B)$ for a pair of outcomes $(a,b)$. Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\bigl|P(A=a,B=b) - P(A=a)P(B=b)\bigr|
&= \bigl|P(A=a|B=b)P(B=b) - P(A=a)P(B=b)\bigr|\\
&= P(B=b) \cdot \bigl|P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a)\bigr|.
\end{align}
$$

Next we need to get a handle on the quantity $|P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a)|$. We can do this by marginalizing over the possible values of $B$:
$$
\begin{align}
\bigl|P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a)\bigr| = \Bigl|P(A=a|B=b) - \sum_{b'} P(A=a,B=b')\Bigr| \\
= \bigl|P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a,B=b) - P(A=a,B\not=b)\bigr|\\
= \bigl|P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a|B=b)\,P(B=b) - P(A=a,B\not=b)\bigr|.
\end{align}
$$

We can factor $P(A=a|B=b)$ out of the first two terms giving us
$$
\begin{align}
\bigl|(1 - P(B=b)) \,  P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a,B\not=b)\bigr| =\\
\bigl|P(B\not=b) \, P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a,B\not=b)\bigr|.~~
\end{align}
$$

Last we can write $P(A=a,B\not=b)$ as the product $P(A=a|B\not=b)\,P(B\not=b)$ so that we can factor out $P(B\not=b)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\bigl|P(B\not=b) \, P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a,B\not=b)\bigr| =\\
\bigl|P(B\not=b) \, P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a|B\not=b)\,P(B\not=b)\bigr|=\\
P(B\not=b)\,\bigl|P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a|B\not=b)\bigr|.
\end{align}
$$

This makes the original quantity, $|P(A=a,B=b) - P(A=a)P(B=b)|$, equal to
$$
P(B=b) \, P(B\not=b)\,\bigl|P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a|B\not=b)\bigr|.
$$

Notice that $|P(A=a|B=b) - P(A=a|B\not=b)| \in [0,1]$ and that
$$
P(B=b)\cdot P(B\not=b) = P(B=b)\cdot (1 - P(B=b))
$$
We can use basic calculus to show that the function $f(x) = x\cdot (1-x)$ is maximized at $x=1/2$. Therefore, $P(B=b)\cdot (1 - P(B=b))$ is maximized when $P(B=b) = 1/2$.

Therefore, the original quantity is less than $(1/2)\cdot (1/2) = 1/4$.