# Proof of two combinatorics identities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would like to proof two combinatorics identities. (I don't know if I can call them that way). We have two events, A and B. P is sign for probability.
For any two events worth:
$$P(A \cup B)P(A \cap B) \leq P(A)P(B)$$
Second is:
$$|P(A \cap B)-P(A)P(B)| \leq \frac{1}{4}$$

These identities apart.

I don't know how to start. But I tried:
Let's use 3 substitutions:
$$x = P(A \setminus B)\\ 
y = P(A \cap B)\\
z = P(B \setminus A)$$
an main idea is to express the probabilities with those substitutions.
Is that correct way of thinking? 
Can someone help me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with $A + B$? is it one of both occuring? Same with $AB$, is this both events occuring at the same time?

Comment: AB mean A and B, both events occuring at same time . A+B is one occuring or both.

Comment: I guess $A+B$ means $A \cup B$ and $AB$ means $A \cap B$.

Comment: Multiplication as "and" and addition as "or" is, while not the standard notation, certainly not unheard of either. There was a time when $\prod$ was used where we now would use $\forall$, and $\sum$ where we now would use $\exists$.

Comment: @Arthur I never saw it this way... I have made an edit, since I thought that the $\cup , \cap$-notation was more convenient (it still has to be peer-reviewed, so it is possible that my edit is not approved).

Comment: @Student I tinkered a bit with your edit before pushing it through. It was good, but I like double dollars.

Comment: @Arthur I will keep it in mind :)

Comment: Hint (for the first part):  using your notation, you are trying to show that $(x+y+z)y≤ (x+y)(z+y)$.

Comment: @lulu many thanks for hint, but what next?

Comment: @Student can yoz help me with this proof?

Comment: Isn't that enough?  expand that product to see that we want to show $xy+y^2+xy≤xz+xy+yz+y^2$ but that is equivalent to showing $0≤xz$.

Comment: I don't see a quick resolution to the second one (which of course doesn't mean that there isn't one).  You have a function of three variables, $F(x,y,z)=y-(x+y)(z+y)$ and you want to find extreme points (subject to $x,y,z≥0$ and $x+y+z≤1$).  That's an easy calculus problem.

Comment: @lulu myb other way (not mine x,y,z...) ?

Comment: I don't understand.  Might there be more conceptual, less algebraic, arguments?  Sure.  I don't see them straight off, but I wouldn't be surprised.  It's true, for example, that for any event $C$ we have $P(C)\times P(\sim C)≤\frac 14$.  Perhaps that helps here?  But at the moment I don't see anything quicker than the algebra.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/980655/413376