# Bounds on $P(A_1\cap \ldots\cap A_n) - P(A_1)\ldots P(A_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

In Székely's [Paradoxes in Probability Theory and Mathematical Statistics](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0880020), it is stated without proof or reference that for any $n\geq 2$ and events $A_1,\ldots,A_n$,
$$-\left(1-\frac 1n\right)^n \leq P(A_1\cap \ldots\cap A_n) - P(A_1)\ldots P(A_n)
\leq \frac{n-1}{n^{n/(n-1)}}.$$

When $n=2$, the bound rewrites as $|P(A_1\cap A_2) - P(A_1) P(A_2)|\leq 1/4$, which is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980655/proving-pa-cap-b-papb-leq-frac14) and tight.
What about $n\geq 3$ ? I'm looking for a reference or a proof.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

THE UPPER BOUND

Let $p=P(A_1\cap \ldots\cap A_n)$ then each $P(A_i)\ge p$.Therefore

$$P(A_1\cap \ldots\cap A_n) - P(A_1)\ldots P(A_n)\le p-p^n.$$
On the interval $0\le p\le 1$, the maximum of $p-p^n$ is attained when $$1-np^{n-1}=0.$$

This gives the upper bound of $\frac{n-1}{n^{n/(n-1)}}$.

THE LOWER BOUND

The union of the $A_i'$ is the complement of $A_1\cap \ldots\cap A_n$ and so has probability $1-p$. Therefore $\Sigma P(A_i') \ge 1-p$.

Then $\Sigma P(A_i) =n-\Sigma P(A_i')\le n-1+p$. Therefore

$$P(A_1\cap \ldots\cap A_n)-P(A_1)\ldots P(A_n)\ge p-\left(\frac{n-1+p}{n}\right)^n.$$

The bound has no T.P. in the interior of $0\le p\le 1$. The minimum is at the endpoint  $p=0$ and is $-(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the crisp solution of @user1172706:

The defining inequalities for $P(A_1\cap \ldots \cap A_n)$ are

$$ -(n-1)+\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) \le P(A_1\cap \ldots A_n) \le \min_{1\le i\le n} P(A_i) $$

i.e. this is the description of the $(n+1)$ convex body of possible values $(P(A_1), \ldots, P(A_n), P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_n) )$.

About the inequality in the post, the LHS $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$ is decreasing with $n$ to $\frac{1}{e}$, and the RHS is increasing with $n$ to $1$. Therefore, an inequality independent of $n$ is meaningful only on LHS
$$-\frac{1}{e} < P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_n) - P(A_1) \cdots P(A_n) $$